# Changing the User Comment EXIF tag (0x9286)

Tags: android, image, comments, metadata, exif

I'm developing an android application and I want to read and update the User Comment EXIF tag.
I just can't find that tag in the ExifInterface.java class. Can I create a custom tag say TAG_USER_COMMENT in ExifInterface? If yes how can I create it? Or should I use another tool do get the job done?

Any help would be very very appreciated.

Comment: If Android doesn't support the EXIF comment, how about the normal JPEG comment (tag FFFE)?

Answer (score 0):

You can write your string data in the EXIF tag called "UserComment" as follows:

```
`import android.media.ExifInterface;`
```

`File directory = new File(your directory goes here);`

`final File image = new File(directory, "name.jpg");`

`ExifInterface interface = new ExifInterface(image.getPath());`

`interface.setAttribute("UserComment", "your string here");`

`interface.saveAttributes();`

Then you can read your data using getAttribute as follows:

`String my_data = interface.getAttribute("UserComment");`

It will not work for some images